# Differences between the GameCube and N64 version of Majora's Mask

Tags: version-differences, zelda-majoras-mask

What are the differences between the N64 and GameCube version of *Majora's Mask*?

Is there any difference in graphics or game play? Or is it just a straight port with no changes?

Comment: I know there was a NGC version of OoT which included the Master Quest, but I didn't know Majora's Mask had a NGC version too...

Comment: It was part of the legend of zelda collectors edition disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I own and played this version, and while the game was intended to be a straight port of N64 Majora's Mask it was actually an inferior copy to the original. Inferior sound, occasional freezing, lower framerate, et al. Speculation is that this is because there was the reliance on the expansion pack.

> Although the game mentions "sound irregularities" on the disc as a
>   result of emulating Majora's Mask on the GameCube, no mention was made
>   of another widespread issue. It seems to be common for the game to
>   freeze without warning. Supposedly, this problem can be encountered
>   less if one opts not to use the rumble function. The freezing was
>   supposedly fixed for the Virtual Console release, though players still
>   rarely report freezing. The framerate of the Collector's Edition
>   version of Majora's Mask is also lower than the 20 FPS framerate of
>   the original game, as reported by reviewers. The problems could be
>   caused due to Majora's Mask's reliance on the 4 MB RAM expansion pack.
>   As Ocarina of Time does not use the pack, no problems occur in it.
>   Majora's Mask also presents a high number of graphical issues.

http://zeldawiki.org/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Collector%27s_Edition#Problems